# PHP mysqli bind_param array as parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

The code that I have now is:

```
$stmt = $this->db->getConnection()->prepare("insert into condutor(name, accessLevel, status, lastLoginDate)
                                             values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("siis", $driver['name'],
            $driver['accessLevel'],
            $driver['status'],
            $driver['lastLoginDate']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
$stmt->bind_param("siis", $driver);
```

instead of passing each variable as a parameter pass the array?